# adding SBJson framwork + ShareKit/ShareKit to the same XCode Project

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, sharekit, sbjson

I want to include SBJson and Sharekint libraries in my Xcode Project the problem is sharekit already contains SBJson but with different methods .. the result is that i ended up with duplicate files containing different code  and hence i receive "duplicate symbole" error at compile time .

what would be a solution that wouldn't involve renaming file names and classes because the code will endup to be a complete mess.

thnks in advance .

Comment: offtopic: take a look at https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit . JSONKit is faster than SBJSON.

Comment: thnx, I'm intending to start using this JSONKit starting next project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SBJson is used in FBConnect. Few solutions come to my mind:

1. If you do not use Facebook, you can remove whole sharer from your project (with older sbjson).
2. Audit SBJson methods used in your project, and if possible refactor them to use FBConnect's version. Then you can get rid of your project's SBJson files.
3. even better, if you support only iOS 5+ you might get rid of SBJson in your project completely, and use native iOS 5 NSJSONSerialization class. This is more future-safe solution than 2.

Comment: thanks for the clear explanation !  I ended up doing choice 2 but it was more convenient for my project to refactor the sharkit Json to use my project SBJson

Comment: I am glad I could help. If you feel the answer was helpful, you might consider to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Make one folder common with all methods of SBJson and delete the other one ..  this will work